# How do I get Sage to properly simplify the result of solving an integral equation?

Tags: python, physics, symbolic-math, sage

Here's my code:

```
E, x, m, omega, hbar = var('E x m omega hbar', domain = 'positive')
n = var('n', domain = 'integer')
assume(n > 0)

V = 0.5*m*omega^2*x^2
assume(V > E)

p = sqrt(2*m*(V-E))

x1 = 0
x2 = sqrt(2)*sqrt(E/m)/omega #solve([E == V],x)[0]

p_int = simplify(integrate(p, x, x1, x2))

show(p_int)

show(simplify(solve(p_int == (n-0.25)*pi*hbar, E)))
```

For context, I'm trying to get an approximate solution to the Schrodinger equation for a particle trapped in a well given the potential function

$V(x) = 0.5 m \omega^2 x^2 \text{ if } x>0, \infty \text{ otherwise }$
by applying the WKB approximation, which, following my textbook, gives the integral equation defined in the above code.

The actual result of evaluating the integral should be $\frac{\pi E}{2\omega}$.
And the solution to the equation is $E_n = \left(2n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\hbar\omega$

But when I run the code I get this output:
[image]

I'm thinking those expressions are probably equivalent to the simpler ones from the textbook, but it's not very useful to have the results in such a complicated form and I can't figure out what the problem is.  I thought perhaps the issue was that it was assuming everything was a complex number, so I explicitly specified the domains, but it made no difference.  And, as you can see, I've already applied the `simplify` function to both expressions.

I don't what else to try, since the code itself runs fine.  I initially did this problem with SymPy in regular Python, but it kept simply giving the wrong answers for both the integral and the equation.  I finally gave up on SymPy altogether, as I've found it to be hit or miss with its ability to evaluate certain integrals symbolically anyway.  But, if I understand correctly, Sage is supposed to be a powerhouse when it comes to both symbolic and numeric computation, merging together a whole bunch of different Python packages into one, so if it's also not giving me the expected answer, I figure I must be doing something wrong in how I'm setting up the code, but I can't see what.  This isn't that complicated a problem to code and I've written similar code before and had no problems.  So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I guess replacing `0.5` with a proper rational number expression in `V` would at least get rid of `0.7071...` in the final expression.